# How to find SAD(sum-of-absolute-differences) in list haskell

Tags: haskell

I need help in finding SAD between elements in a list using haskell.The program should take the a list of numbers and perform absolute difference and sum all of the absolute differences.

```
sumDiff:: Num a => [a] -> a
Input : sumDiff [1, 4, -6, 6]
Expected output : 25
```

I am new to haskell and I dont know how to work with lists.Please help me :/

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No I am not a student.I am getting lots of type errors . I am not understanding how to implement the logic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't learn the bare basics of a new programming language by asking questions on SO. You should use a tutorial or textbook.

Comment: Lots of people like Learn You A Haskell.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any good reference books for a beginner.

Comment: Link: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints, you can write the program almost translated from the spec

differences in elements

```
 diff xs = zipWith (-) xs $ tail xs
```

absolute value and sum functions are `abs` and `sum`.  To take the absolute value of all elements of a list, you need to `map`